# struggling to install python package via amazon sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Amazon Sagemaker and trying to install gaapi4py package via anaconda python3 notebook.

So far I've tried the following commands:

```
%conda install gaapi4py
```

and

```
conda install gaapi4py

Got same error:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64'



Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Alternatively I've tried the below but it failed as well:

```
pip install gaapi4py
```

Error text:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f657c803c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/gaapi4py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f657c8035f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/gaapi4py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f657c803550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/gaapi4py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f657c803400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/gaapi4py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f657c803358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/gaapi4py/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gaapi4py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gaapi4py
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

What am I doing wrong? All previous packages worked well.

UPD:

Tried also as recommended in amazon book:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install gaapi4py
```

and

```
import sys
!conda install -y --prefix {sys.prefix} gaapi4py
```

Both didn't work neither, getting same errors as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking back-in-forth with our IT department I figured out that custom libraries installation was blocked for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error:

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url

It was because the notebook was not able to connect to the internet. I had created the notebook in a private VPC. I created a new notebook with "Direct internet access" enabled. Then I was able to install packages.